# Adding an extra section to wordpress 'Add a Post' page

Tags: wordpress

I know this may seem like a very weird question, but is there any way I could manually (code) add an extra section to the Publish module in add a post? Or even like an extra pop up before you click submit as like a confirmation?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkXyF.png

Comment: https://wpbrigade.com/how-to-add-a-custom-field-in-wordpress-via-wordpress-plugin/ see this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could easily add new elements to this section using one of these three action hooks:

- [post_submitbox_minor_actions](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_submitbox_minor_actions/)
- [post_submitbox_misc_actions](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_submitbox_misc_actions/)
- [post_submitbox_start](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_submitbox_start/)

Here's an image which shows where content echoed on these hooks would appear:

[Publish box hook locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruJDS.png)

Comment: Would I be able to put a drop down menu with options, which i can then use to filter post by those options?

Comment: You can echo any html you like, so if you want to put an html select element in there then of course. You would then also need to create the accompanying code for carrying out any actions based on the usage of those elements, and I'm not sure what posts you are wanting to filter, but there's no specific limitation on that space.